# VSTS Yaml Build - App Center Service Endpoint could not be found

Tags: build, azure-devops, yaml, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I'm trying to setup my build definition with YAML. I'm using the [AppCenterDistribute task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AppCenterDistribute). It requires and endpoint to MS App Center. I've setup one as per this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/api-docs/).

However, I got that error message:

> "Step input serverEndpoint references endpoint *Appcenter* which could not be found. The service endpoint does not exist or has not been authorized for use."

This is exactly the same issue as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123590/vsts-app-center-yaml-endpoint-could-not-be-found?rq=1#) although I've made sure that I AM in the correct VSTS project.

What could be the problem?  I can't even run my build now.

Here's the YAML section:

variables:

```
APKName: 'com.project.this.apk'
- task: AppCenterDistribute@1
displayName: Deploy APK to App Center
inputs:
  serverEndpoint: Appcenter
  appSlug: 'Project/Learn'
  appFile: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\$(APKName)'
  symbolsIncludeParentDirectory: false
  releaseNotesInput: Notes
```

Note that I do have a normal VSTS web build (with a slightly different name) in the same VSTS project that does build and can distribute using the same endpoint to App Center.

Here's the error when I submit a YAML build:

[image: Submit build error]

Answer (score 1):

I can also reproduce the issue when the App Center Distribute task is added in a YAML build definition.

And I also create an issue [App Center Distribute task show errors when queuing YAML build](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/7350) for it. You can follow up.

Answer (score 1):

You followed the App Center tutorial but you still have to create the Endpoint in VSTS which I think is what you're missing. It cannot be done through your Yaml.

To do so, connect to VSTS and start creating a new empty-process build definition MANUALLY for the SAME project. Add the the "App Center Distribute" task. There is a dropdown for the endpoint. It is empty and there is a "New" button to create one. Do so and give it the name that you use in your Yaml. Then you can cancel your build definition creation and use your Yaml.

[image]

UPDATE:

I replied too fast as you said you already have a build defintion working fine with your App Center endpoint. I still keep the above as it could help others.

However, when I compare your Yaml to mine, I notice that I use quotes while you don't. That may be the issue (also I may just have quotes because I have a space in my endpoint name and you don't).

```
serverEndpoint: 'App Center'
```

On your existing working build definition, did you try the "View Yaml" button on the top right corner? This gives you the corresponding yaml and it is very useful :-)

[image]

Comment: Have you queued your yaml build yet? The quotes makes no change. Since your server name `App Center` contains blank space, the quotes are necessary. While my service name is `MyAppCenter` without blank space, quotes are unnecessary in my yml file.

Comment: As I've said on github, I can't click on Queue Build button due to the error. Also, I have already setup the serviceendpoint. my web ui build works as expected.